# Editing header.phtml in cPanel

Tags: magento-1.9, header

I'm quite new to html coding and particularly Magento, so please be gentle.

My question is: is it ok to edit **header.phtml**

(location - `public_html/app/design/frontend/xyz/default/template/page/html`)

with cPanel Code Editor? I mean .. it is a “live” action and I’m afraid of not ruining something or the website itself...

All I want to do is to edit a phone number from the header, which is not available anymore.
I have looked for the header in the `administration/control` panel of the site, but I found everything, except for this tiny section with the phone number.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of: editing on a live site is always bad practice. No matter what framework you are using.

Secondly: Seeing the phone number in the header is no guarantee that it's literally in the header template:

- If the template is build by someone who knows how-to-magento, he would have used the Magento system configuration (where the phone number is stored). If so, you can simply edit the phone number by logging into Magento and edit it there (as suggested by [Fme Extensions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/38435/fme-extensions)).
- If the template is build by someone who doesn't understand Magento and hard-coded the phone number in your template, then yeah... editing the template is probably the right action to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Log into your Magento Admin Panel Go to **System -> Configuration** Click
>    on the **General** button in the left side menu panel Click on the **Store
>    Information** and fill in the Store Contact Telephone.

*change it there if you are in luck. otherwise maybe  hardcoded in header.phtml*